# aws python sdk boto3 client route53domains get_domain_suggestions ClientError

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-route53

```
>>> import boto3
>>> r53d = boto3.client('route53domains', aws_access_key_id='(removed)', aws_secret_access_key='(removed)', region_name='us-east-1') 
>>> response = r53d.get_domain_suggestions(DomainName='example', SuggestionCount=5, OnlyAvailable=True)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/user/.pyenv/versions/webev.net/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 159, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/home/user/.pyenv/versions/webev.net/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 494, in _make_api_call
    raise ClientError(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (InvalidInput) when calling the GetDomainSuggestions operation: Errors: [Give domain name must contain more than 1 label]
```

A google search of **"aws boto route53 Give domain name must contain more than 1 label"** or of variations yields nothing, and I can't seem to find the ClientError exceptions documentation... Any help?

EDIT: From what I can tell all of my parameters are OK according to the [docs](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/route53domains.html#Route53Domains.Client.get_domain_suggestions), and `response = r53d.list_domains()` works so I know it's not the `boto3.client` parameters.

Comment: looks like a bug. `get_domain_suggestions()` expects a TLD. So you need to give more than one label for `DomainName`

Comment: @helloV the docs state **"a string with (or without) top-level domain specified"** and `DomainName='example'` or `DomainName='example.com'` have the same result. That is what I'm trying to figure out, what giving more than one label for `DomainName` means...

Comment: Thats why said it is a bug. Code and doc are not in Sync. You need to provide TLD (extra label) for this to work.

Comment: @helloV Oh `DomianName='example.com'` _is working_... I could have sworn it was reproducing the same results last night. Sorry about that! If you want to post an answer I'll accept it. Thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contrary to what [Boto3 documentation](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/route53domains.html#Route53Domains.Client.get_domain_suggestions) says, `get_domain_suggestions()` expects a valid TLD. Passing `example.com` should return some results.

```
>>> for val in r53d.get_domain_suggestions(DomainName='google.com', SuggestionCount=5, OnlyAvailable=True)['SuggestionsList']: print val['DomainName']
6oo6l3.com
moveogle.com
googleannounces.com
googleunveils.com
adwordsonline.com
```